# On associated prime ideals of reduced commutative rings $R$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

How can I prove the following statement?

If $R$ is a reduced Noetherian commutative ring, then every associated prime ideal of $R$ is a minimal prime ideal of $R$.

Comment: Browsing your recent question history, it seems you are lately asking only Problem-Statement-Question style questions. That is, you are not meeting the [standards for question quality](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error). This is likely to draw negative attention to your questions, especially if it persists. Consider reviewing these guidelines and revising your questions accordingly to save yourself the trouble. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An associated prime consists entirely of zero divisors.  You should be able to express the set of zero divisors of a reduced ring in terms of minimal prime ideals, and to say something about the number of minimal primes in a noetherian ring.  At this point, hopefully the way is clear.